# Export rich text format from TFS to Excel

Tags: tfs, epplus

I am trying to export TFS 2012 test cases to excel.
currently I was able to export the data to excel as plain text with the following code

```
     foreach (ITestCase Testcase in testcases)
        {
            int j = 1;
            string str1 = null;
            string str2 = null;
            foreach (ITestAction action in Testcase.Actions)
            {
                ISharedStep shared_step = null;
                ISharedStepReference shared_ref = action as ISharedStepReference;
                if (shared_ref != null)
                {
                    shared_step = shared_ref.FindSharedStep();
                    foreach (ITestAction shr_action in shared_step.Actions)
                    {
                        var test_step = shr_action as ITestStep;
                        str1 = str1 + j.ToString() + "." + ((test_step.Title.ToString().Length ==0)? "<<Not Recorded>>" : test_step.Title.ToPlainText()) + System.Environment.NewLine;
                        str2 = str2 + j.ToString() + "." + ((test_step.ExpectedResult.ToString().Length ==0) ? "<<Not Recorded>>" : test_step.ExpectedResult.ToPlainText()) + System.Environment.NewLine;
                        j++;
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    var test_step = action as ITestStep;
                    str1 = str1 + j.ToString() + "." + ((test_step.Title.ToString().Length ==0) ? "<<Not Recorded>>" : test_step.Title.ToPlainText()) + System.Environment.NewLine;
                    str2 = str2 + j.ToString() + "." + ((test_step.ExpectedResult.ToString().Length ==0) ? "<<Not Recorded>>" : test_step.ExpectedResult.ToPlainText()) + System.Environment.NewLine;
                    j++;
                }
            }
            oSheet.Cells[i, 1].Value = Testcase.Id.ToString();
            oSheet.Cells[i, 2].Value = Testcase.Title.ToString();
            oSheet.Cells[i, 3].Value =  str1;
            oSheet.Cells[i, 4].Value = str2;
            ParameterizedString Description = Testcase.Description;
            oSheet.Cells[i, 5].Value = Description.ToPlainText();
            i++;
        }
```

I'm using EPPlus.dll to write to the excel file.

My Question is how to export formatted text?

Answer (score 0):

Why you are trying to code it?

Download "test case extractor" to excel and export all test cases to excel sheets.

Comment: test case extractor only supports TFS 2010 and this code supports tfs 2012 with the same functionality as in TFS 2010.
But I want to export the rich rich text not just the plain text.

Comment: kindly google for shai raiton post.. he is mvp and did several things for TFS 2012. may be u can ask him or get any help from his articals